# DB connectivity failure in Cypress while running from console

Tags: sql-server, command-line, coffeescript, cypress, tediousjs

I was trying to connect MSSQL from Cypress and finally got a solution by following the steps provided in this link:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6621

The solution worked perfectly fine and able to run the tests from the Cypress App but while trying the same test from the command line it fails with the following error:

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/az7MN.png)

Can someone please help me with a solution on it.

Thanks

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please ignore it as I got it resolved. It was actually picking a wrong config in command line.
Thanks